# android app froze when received a call

Tags: android

i a new programmer. i created an app and it works good. When i was playing in the app i got a call, did not answer and went back to application.

application froze, could not do ANYTHING in the app. Had to exit and restart the app.

how to avoid this problems.

pls anyone teach me

Comment: Your question is lacking almost every required information. How are you handling life-cycle changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to put some code in the onPause() and onResume() method of your app. Try to store all the instance variables in onPause() and try to restore their value in the onResume() method.